# SoapExtensions are used only for ASP.NET

Tags: webrequest

I'm trying to implement a SoapExtension for log purposes (print the xml soap request) on an .NET 2.0 client application (not ASP.NET).
I first tried a simple console application just to check and I'm not able to see that the extension is called.
The simple code is just two lines:

System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.ynet.com");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

and my config file is the following:

What I'm doing wrong? are the extension usable only in ASP.NET?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must have class e.g.:"YourExtension" derived from "SoapExtension" class and attribute class e.g. "YourExtensionAttribute" derived from "SoapExtensionAttribute" there you overide "Type" property:

```
public override Type ExtensionType
{
 get { return typeof(YourExtension); }
}
```

and put SoapExtensionAttribute to your webservice method

Comment: Hi,
I've created my SoapExtension. I've read that instead of using the attribute, you can add what I've add in the config file. If I call a service added by a web reference it works fine, but if I use a WebRequest or HTTPWebRequest it does not work...